# Magento Checkout A/B Testing

Tags: checkout

i am using two different checkout extension in my store. I want to both work randomly for a/b testing is it possible??

Comment: you can try both in different demo/staging/localhost sites and choose one best one.....

Comment: you mean two domain not work on one site both?

Comment: you can do in one domain also, if you want to check one extension , you have to disable another extension & vice versa.....

Comment: yes i can do this but my client want both randomly he installed light checkout and checkout one page he want both work randomly

Comment: for my knowledge, thats not possible, hope someone will give you solution

Comment: yes i think not possible because both have same link thanx for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible , when you install 2 checkout extensions, one extension will override the other extension features, if you want this you need to disable one extension through a**pp/etc/modules** folder. instead of this , its better to test these in 2 different sites.....